# Ranking in Excel, when I want the top n I get the top n+1 (or n+x)

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a list in excel and I'd like it to select the higher 3 results, and only 3. It seems easy to do with conditional formatting in this example:

```
1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6 
44 | 78 | 98 | 45 | 52 | 98
```

Where the 2nd, 3rd and 6th number will be highlighted.

The problem appears with something like this:

```
1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6 
44 | 78 | 78 | 45 | 87 | 98
```

Excel will highlight the 2nd, 3rd, 5th and 6th number, because the first two (the third on a sorted list) are equal.
How can I make Excel select only one of them?

(the solution doesn't need to use conditional formatting, any tools available on Excel can be used, from formulas to VB, but simplicity it's desirable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your conditional formatting, we need to break the tie. One way to do this is to count the number of times a value appears in the previous comparisons.

This would change your conditional formula to

```
=(RANK(A2,$A$2:$F$2)+COUNTIF($A$2:A$2,A2)-1)<=3
```

Note that absolute positions are used in some cases, and relative in others.

Breakdown:
`RANK(A2,$A$2:$F$2)` - Rank formula. You know this one, as you're using it now
`COUNTIF($A$2:A$2,A2)` - count the number of times the value appears - note that the reference does not have a $ in front of the `A` after the colon - this is to ensure that the range gets bigger as we process the formula along the row (1st count: A2:A2, 2nd count: A2:B2, etc)
`-1` - as the count will always match one number (itself)

so, for your second example,

```
44  78  78  45  87  98
```

The new ranks are

```
6   3   4   5   2   1
```

and the formulas convert to

> =RANK(A2,$A$2:$F$2)+COUNTIF($A$2:A$2,A2)-1
>   =RANK(B2,$A$2:$F$2)+COUNTIF($A$2:B$2,B2)-1
>   =RANK(C2,$A$2:$F$2)+COUNTIF($A$2:C$2,C2)-1
>   =RANK(D2,$A$2:$F$2)+COUNTIF($A$2:D$2,D2)-1
>   =RANK(E2,$A$2:$F$2)+COUNTIF($A$2:E$2,E2)-1
>   =RANK(F2,$A$2:$F$2)+COUNTIF($A$2:F$2,F2)-1

for the conditional formatting

Comment: Thanks a lot it did for me. Can I suggest that you remind the reader that formula can be applied to all the cells by the way of the format painter.
Also, the $ can be removed before all the row numbers to enable paste it to other rows.

Comment: if you highlight all the cells, then you can put in this formula as it would be in the first cell, and Excel will then make the adjustments for you, without having to use format painter.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of one cell solution, but here is my take with a helper column:

`Rank_Row` column, check if the `Input` is duplicated, if yes then add fraction of row number. `C2=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,B2)>1,RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$7)+ROW()/100,RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$7))`

`Filter` column is using simple `RANK` in ascending order, you can use this column to filter top 3. `D2=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$7,1)`

Drag down the both formulas to copy down.

[image]